# The user x cannot use this program (crontab)

Tags: ubuntu, cron

Ubuntu 14.04

I don't understand the behaviour I'm seeing with setting up crontab for a service (no login) account (named `curator`).

When I'm logged in as root, this is what I get:

```
# crontab -u curator -l
The user curator cannot use this program (crontab)
```

But, when I switch to the user's account, it works fine:

```
# su -s /bin/bash curator
curator@host$ crontab -l
no crontab for curator
```

There is an empty `/etc/cron.allow` file and no `/etc/cron.deny` file on the system. According to `man crontab`:

> If  the  /etc/cron.allow file exists, then you must be listed (one user per line) therein in order to be allowed to use this command. If the /etc/cron.allow file does not exist but the /etc/cron.deny file does exist, then you must not be listed in the /etc/cron.deny file in order to use this command.

I understand the error when I'm running the first command, but why does it allow me to run `crontab` when I explicitly switch to the user's account?

Adding the user to `/etc/cron.allow` makes both commands work fine.

Comment: It just says that there is no crontab. What will happen if you try to create one via `crontab -e` (as user curator)?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this issue on the vagrant trusty64 image; with an empty `cron.allow` file, both the `root` `crontab -u vagrant -l` and `crontab -l` as `vagrant` result in a `are not allowed to use this program` message (which is different from the message you quote).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I checked the crontab sources and found that if the user cannot open `/etc/cron.allow` (for instance after `chmod 0 /etc/cron.allow`), crontab thinks the user is allowed to use it (as if `cron.allow` did not exist).

But root can read any file, so crontab checking code works as expected. So I recommend you to check first permissions on `/etc/cron.allow`, and maybe SELinux/AppArmor audit logs.

Comment: This seems to be it - I have verified that `chmod -r /etc/cron.allow` indeed causes the described behavior on my Ubuntu 14.04 system

Comment: Spot on! My `/etc/cron.allow` permissions were `600`, after changing it to `644` both `root` and `curator` saw the `not allowed to use this program (crontab)` message. Then, after adding `curator` to `/etc/cron.allow` both could use curator's crontab.